# Random reordering of TENNESSEE.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a random reordering of the letters in “TENNESSEE”. What is the probabilityof each of the following?

(a) All the E’s are together?
In this case I considered TENNESSEE like TENNSS
If I can notice the difference between E, N, S among themselves then

all reordering of TENNESSE: 3780 =9!/2! 4! 2!

for TENNSS 180 = 780/2*2

then  the probability is 0.0476

(b) Both of the S’s come before the T.

I thought...

ssteeeenn 105 possibles reordering+ ?+?

**But I can not see how to calculate the others, I'm stuck in this part. Thanks!**

In this case I fixed N, therefore I have N TEEEESS N and I reordering the inside,and the I divided by 3780. sol:0.0278

Thanks!

Comment: There is a simple solution to b). Forget about the other letters. For any particular **set** of places S, S, and T jointly occupy, it is equally likely that the T is first, in the middle, or last, so the probability is $1/3$.  See whether you can get this by a counting argument using all the letters.

Comment: In part (a), it looks like you meant $180 = \frac{\color{red}{720}}{2 \cdot 2}$.